# ffmpeg convert mp4 video for phones

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, centos, converters

I need to make a video which will play on iPhone and Android but the problem is when I click play on the phone it needs minimum 7 seconds to start.

So maybe I need to fix something in this code to make the video play on phones (maybe another format is needed):

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO -c:v libx264 -s 640x480 -strict experimental -c:a aac VIDEO.MP4
```

There must be something to make the video play faster without a delay on start.

I tried a `FLV` file and it worked fine on Android but the iPhone can't play it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to a progressive download scenario then you can use:

**-movflags faststart**

> Run a second pass moving the index (moov atom) to the beginning of the
>   file. This operation can take a while, and will not work in various
>   situations such as fragmented output, thus it is not enabled by
>   default.

[Source](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mov_002c-mp4_002c-ismv)

The moov atom is generally at the end of the file and a full download is required before playback in this case. Moving it to the start with the aforementioned command allows the playback to start immediately.

Comment: I believe it should specifically be `-movflags +faststart` so it will be added to any default flags; if the `+` is omitted it will clear any default flags (not that I've tested this though).